# How to get the default alert Dialog on android have a black theme

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

How do you get the black themed Dialog in android like shown on the android guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

I took a screen shot. Whenever I use Alert Dialog, I get the dialog on the left, I want the one on the right.

[image]

Comment: Try this but not sure. Go to android project-->layout-->xml file-->Graphical Layout-->change theme (Theme.Black)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <style name="default_activity_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityMain"
          android:theme="@style/default_activity_theme"/>
```

Comment: oh so its just using a theme for that particular activity!
Fantastic!

Comment: There is an easy and proper way to do this, see my answer below.

Comment: .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)

Answer (score 38):

It's simple for API 11 onwards:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
```

The field `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK` was added in API 14 so if you are targeting before then, just use the numeric value, thus:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, 4);
```

The different constants you can use, and their values are shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK). On pre API 14 you will still get the white alert though.

----------------------------------------------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------------------------------------

`AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK` is depreciated,

Below is the updated code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

You can choose different themes instead of this `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert`

Comment: `THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`...How to fix?

Comment: This theme worked for me, to get a light theme: `Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert`

Comment: The dark one is now `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert` according to your link (and my experiments): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your `Activity`'s theme, you can extend `AlertDialog` and supply the `Theme.Holo` in its contructor: `AlertDialog(Context context, int theme)`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using `DialogFragment` to implement customised dialog, set the theme in `onCreate()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog)
}
```